# VSCode Java extension color highlighting in blank color theme

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I am working on a color theme for vscode. I was getting some unexpected highlights.

I have deleted all entries in the color theme. It has no colors specified at all. Just the background color.

I have noticed than when I place my cursor at the front of a variable name, that string is highlighted in blue, and subsequent occurrences of the same string are highlighted in grey.

[image]

These colors are not defined anywhere in my empty color theme.

When I enable the java extension, these colors show, when I disable the java extension they are absent.

Anyone know where these colors are coming from?

Comment: This is a function that VS Code provides for developers to check the variable conveniently, which choose the variable in blue, and if the variable is referenced, it will show it in grey.

Comment: How do I change the color of this highlight?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to change it cause it doesn't depend on any extensions installed that we can change settings to achieve this goal but VS Code it self provides.